# Trying to remove slope bounce

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

So I am making something in unity for VR and am trying to remove slope bounce when going down slopes. Every tutorial I see is manipulating the player movement functions in the player script, but I am using the Action Based Continuous Move Provider for my movement so I don't have access to that stuff do I?

Basically, I am wondering how to smooth slope movement when using this locomotion system.

I have tried looking at a bunch of Youtube tutorials but they all end up modifying the players' movement directly so that it is parallel with the plane you're walking up. I understand it but I'm not sure how to do it with the continuous move provider.

Comment: Most likely, you are going to have to add another script onto the player to manipulate it.

Comment: Yeah I already have a player script on the go which handles jumping and dashing (and a few other things), but it basically just adds force onto the rigidbody. Since I don't control the directional movement with this script though I'm not sure how to adjust it to be parallel with the plane as I have no way of manipulating its' direction through the script.